# Can I / Should I use WordPress as a CMS for my Flash application

Tags: cms

I sometimes build applications in Flash for the web that need a fair bit of dynamic data. Would WordPress be a good fit for my CMS solution? can it "talk" to flash? Does it allow output as different formats such as XML, JSON, or AMF?

Comment: Wordpress is written on PHP. So, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. WordPress is implemented in PHP and anything Flash needed to interface with can be coded as a plugin, probably very easily. You can also implement any embedding of Flash as [ShortCodes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/).

Here are some (honestly not very good) links on the subject of PHP & Flash:

- http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/displayinphp.htm
- http://www.techmynd.com/get-data-in-flash-from-php/
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/9848-pass-complex-data-from-php-to-flash/
- http://www.video-animation.com/dbase001.shtml
- http://www.smartwebby.com/Flash/external_data.asp
- http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/36748

Of course then there is what Adobe has:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=php+flash+data+site:adobe.com

Can you update your question to provide more details on exactly what you need for/from Flash? Maybe included some links that explain the things you want WordPress handling for Flash (Flash is quite a large beast, you know.)

Comment: +1 Wordpress has no problem incorporating custom (X)HTML. You retain full control of the source, it's just a case of finding the right plug-ins to make it simple to embed and/or dropping some php code into a page template.

Answer (score 1):

In re: XML, remember too that WordPress has (even without a plugin) a very nice XML-RPC interface.

See, e.g. http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [loadvars() function in flash](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/loadVars/). It basically works together with the [PHP urlencode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) so you can send small bits of data to your flash movie. This should work with flash 2 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's going to involve a lot of work to get it to send the right information in the right format. You might look into this plugin that puts the information out in JSON:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/